# PHP C Extension Global Memory Management

Tags: php, php-extension

I'm writing a C extension that should allocate a global array when the module inits (that array doesn't change and is relevant for every request). I've read about php c extensions memory management, but most sources don't mention declaring variables on the stack.

Is that still a valid approach, or is it more likely to leak in which case I should prefer pemalloc, etc...?

Some sample code to illustrate the question:
In my header:

```
ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS(myExtension)
long long myArray[ARRAY_SIZE];
ZEND_END_MODULE_GLOBALS(myExtension)
```

And in the implementation:

```
PHP_MINIT_FUNCTION(myExtension) {
    fillUpMyArray();
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: couldn't this be done with memcache?

Comment: The real thing is a bit more complex than this code sample :) I currently use APC to store the data, but it's still too slow (loading a massive array and searching through it). The C version is orders of magnitude faster

Comment: if you have to start extending it like this, perhaps php is not the language to use in the first place

Comment: php is mostly fine. This is a large site, with a large codebase and millions of daily users. PHP allows us to develop quickly and everyone on the dev team knows it. There's only a couple of pieces of php that I'm rewriting in C because they're bottlenecks. Starting over isn't an option :(

Answer (score 2):

There are basically two different kinds of memory usage from within a php extension:

- **thread-local storage**, which in zend-speak are "thread safe global" variables, usable during a specific request;
  needs to be set up in `ZEND_GINIT_FUNCTION(myExtension)` and torn down in `ZEND_GSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(myExtension)` [available when ZEND_MODULE_API_NO >=20060613, php >=5.2.0]
- **process-wide storage**, which is referred to with the term "persistent data";
  needs to be set up statically and/or in `ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(myExtension)` and torn down statically and/or in `ZEND_MSHUTDOWN_FUNCTION(myExtension)`

With the `ZEND_BEGIN_MODULE_GLOBALS` macro you declare thread safe global variables, what you really want is persistent data.

**(!)** Please note that php only knows the data type `long`, not `long long`.

What you don't tell is how exactly you're using you array.
For your specific case you could simply use a static array, defined in your .c/.cpp file, plus an array access function:

```
static long myArray[ARRAY_SIZE];

ZEND_MINIT_FUNCTION(myExtension)
{
    fillUpMyArray();
    return SUCCESS;
}

ZEND_FUNCTION(myext_get)
{
    long idx;

    if (zend_parse_parameters_ex(0, ZEND_NUM_ARGS() TSRMLS_CC, "l", &idx) == FAILURE)
        RETURN_NULL();

    // TODO check array bounds!

    RETURN_LONG(myArray[idx]);
}
```